# How to get the id of a dynamically created label element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pug

I want to get the text of a dynamically created label in javascript, which is created in jade. Here's the jade:

```
- for( var i = 0; i < groupsName.length; i++ ) {
  li
    a(href='JavaScript:validation(this)')
        img(src='/images/edit.png', width='60', height='60', style='margin:8px 10px 10px 20px;')  
         h3 #{groupsName[0]}
          label(for='groupsId' , id='labelid'+i ) #{groupsId[i]}
      a(href='/groupdetails') Edit  
  - }
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
 function validation(val){
   var valid=val.id;
   alert(document.getElementById(valid).innerHTML);
 }
```

Comment: Is it not working? What appears in the alert box? Do you get any errors?

Comment: <% for( var i = 0; i < groupsId.length; i++ ) {%>
       <li>
         <a href='JavaScript:validation(this)'>
        img<src='/images/edit.png' width='60'    height='60' style='margin:8px 10px 10px 20px;'/>
           <label<for='groupsId'  id='labelid'+i > #{groupsId[i]}      </label>
           </a>
  </li>
      <%}%>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm interpreting your template correctly, but as long as the dynamic label is descendant of the anchor tag which triggers the validation this should work:

First replace the `href` by an `onclick` otherwise the `this` being passed will reference the `window`. The generated anchor tag should look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="validation(this);">
```

Then just adapt your function slightly:

```
function validation(anchor) {
    var lbl = anchor.getElementsByTagName('label')[0];
    alert(lbl.innerHTML);
    alert(lbl.id);
}​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6VnBr/1/)